# Why can I override the font color on the `li`'s and not on the `P` tag's content?

Tags: html, css

In this code:

```
...
<div class="job-overview no-company-desc">
  <h2 class="job-overview-title">Overview</h2>
    <p>Jamit&#8217;s client is looking for a Senior Software Engineer constantly iterating and pushing releases into production.</p>
<p><strong>Qualifications:</strong></p>
<ul>
<li>Experience leading a team of developers by example – following excellent coding habits and best practices</li>
<li>Experience in an Agile software development environment in a web context</li>
<li>A thorough understanding of how business needs drive product features</li>
<li>Demonstrated expertise with the entire software development life cycle</li>
</ul>
            </div>
```

There are various css stylesheets included, by I try to override them by putting my css code last in the header, i.e.

```
<style type="text/css">
  p { color: blue; }
  li { color: blue; }
</style>
```

This makes the list of `LI` items be in blue but not the `P` content.  Any suggestions on making the `P` content be blue also?

Comment: There must be more CSS.. it works here http://jsfiddle.net/cn9Nd/

Comment: Try to make the CSS selectors more specific.

Comment: I tried `  .job-overview no-company-desc p { color: blue; }` but it didn't help.

Comment: You need to post code that actually reproduces the problem. Just saying “There are various css stylesheets included” means here that you have omitted the essential information from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current context, it is fine - there must be some more CSS that has more specificity. Either **remove** that, or be more specific. `!imporant` **will** fix this, however I **do not** suggest using it. [**Reason here.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css)

If you can't remove the original styles, try overwritting it..

```
div.job-overview.no-company-desc p {
    color: blue;
}
```

Alternatively, and more specifically, you can use: (assuming the `p` follows `h2`.)

```
div.job-overview.no-company-desc h2 + p {
    color: blue;
}
```

If specificity isn't the answer, then the solution is the order in which the CSS is being applied. Aside from that, if you are trying to overwrite inline styling - you can't, unless you use `!important`.